# Why is it in the middle and not the top?

Tags: html, css

I've almost got my website finished but am growing incredibly frustrated and not being able to get the vertical-align to work. Everywhere else, my content is where it should be, but for reasons unknown, these lists are appearing in the middle... meaning when the iframe is set to the desired size, my lists move to the middle of their td?

I've tried adding the vertical align option to the css of the links, created a div option for the entire area, adding it html etc, no luck anywhere? What am I doing wrong? :(

```
A.class2 {text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 16px;}
A.class2:link, A.class2:visited {color: #0fa616;}
A.class2:hover, A.class2:active {color: #0fa616;}

#sub li {list-style-type: square;}
```

Please bear in mind that I have a main ul menu above that I do not want affected in any code anyone manages to fix for me.

```
<center><h2>Amber w/Inclusions</h2></center><ul id="sub">
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Baltic</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Copal</a></li>
</ul>

<center><h2>Dinosaurs/Reptiles</h2></center>
<ul id="sub">
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Pterosaur</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Raptor</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Spinosaurus</a></li>
</ul>

<center><h2>Trilobites</h2></center>
<ul id="sub">
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Cambrian age</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Devonian age</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="class2">Ordovician age</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see what I mean on the page http://www.dinodeals.co.uk/fossils.html
The table itself is only for aid during design, it won't be visible on the complete design. I would love a little divider also, say a green line to the right of the entire sub category menu I'm trying to set to the top. But had no luck implimenting that either after reading up how. I'm not sure the border-right css is usable anymore?

Comment: Adding `vertical-align:top` to the containing cell works fine for me.

Comment: arg... I would recommend not using "table" elements for layout...

Comment: other than that, yeah, just set the vertical-align on the "td" element.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to the css element of building. I learnt html 15 years ago and haven't built a site in forever. It's all a little overwhelming assigning classes to things and such. Appreciate the replies and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, I just inspected the page and found you are running some type of padding on your `td` element (most likely caused by it aligning to the middle).

Try this little snippet:

```
td{
padding-top: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

This aligned the table to the top on my screen.

**EDIT:**

As per your request for border on the right of it (I didn't see that far into the question).

```
td{
vertical-align: top;
border-right: 3px solid rgb(15, 166, 22);
padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very new to css, having learned html 15 years ago, fair few changes now haha. Everything is working perfectly once I assigned a class to it. Thanks again for your help